# Отсутствует функционал для включения и выключения света в Unreal Engine 4

Tags: unreal-engine-4

Речь о [Blueprints Visual Scripting](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Blueprints/index.html)

Документация гласит, что я могу использовать `Toggle Visibility` для включения и выключения света, но в моей Unreal Engine такая функция отсутствует.
В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Версии совпадают? Я имею введу по которой документация и на которой Вы что-то делаете? Я по невнимательности своей и не такое еще делал, как пример. :)

Comment: @Ilja, я тоже об этом думал, но вроде как документация самая новая на сайте и самую актуальную версию UE скачал же. . .

Comment: Посмотрите пример реализации Toggle Visibility в Realistic Rendering, а именно в map Night No Lights Scene Lighting на основе простого фонарика. И какая версия Unreal Engine?